# How deliver content (images) with an Android app?

Tags: android, google-play

I built an Android app that I want to release in the Google Play Store. The only thing I need to figure out is the proper way to deliver all the content with the app, in specific the images.

The content of the application is about 300 images. I'm wondering what the best way is to deliver all the images with the application. Or where to put these images. The images will always be used in the app.

I read that the assets folder is not meant to store images in. So I think that it is not the solution to my question.

So what should I use to deliver the content? The APK Expansion Files? Just the res folder? Or something better?

**EDIT**:
It looks like a problem to me that the APK will be very huge when I put 300 images in the **res** folder.

Comment: go with the `res` folder until you come across another problem

Comment: `res/drawables/` or any local directory is not a place to store many images. With any considerable size, 300 images would result in a huge APK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most applications utilize some sort of backend, whether that be a custom application, a mBaaS, or large cloud platforms like AWS, Azure, or Google Cloud.

If you don't currently have a backend, consider your requirements for future possible features of your application. If you only need a place to manage images, perhaps something like [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/) would suit your needs.

Comment: But isn't it better when the images are local available instead of somewhere in the cloud?

Comment: No, for reasons stated in my other comment.

Comment: But now it is a MUST that you have an active internet connection because the images are online? But I don't want that.

Comment: You can cache images after install. The point is no user is going to want your 300 images to be saved on their device. `/res/drawables/` is mainly for small images like icons and the like. Shipping a few images with your app is fine, but it is not a viable solution for the number you've specified.